# Puppet - importing a locally written (non-installed) module's functions

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

Say I have two locally extant modules that don't exist on Forge or in a custom Forge-like repo. These repos will never be installed via command line as they are part of a bigger deployment that cannot use the Forge-like installation commands - they are put there by hand or by repo cloning.

`ModuleA` defines a function in its `functions` folder, and is invokable in the scope of `ModuleA`. All good.

`ModuleB` tries to invoke the function from `ModuleA` and fails as [due to the module not being installed and findable for the JSON manifest](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.2/lang_write_functions_in_puppet.html#calling-a-function).

Can this limitation be gotten around nicely? Classes can be invoked in this way - I don't want to sacrifice good design for this awkward limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out - if you wish to import functions for a module in the same space all you need to do is include the module in `dependencies` in the `metadata.json` file for the module that is importing (ModuleB in my above question). The usage of `manifest` in their documentation is confusing - including it in the `metadata` would be more correct.

So a dependency node in the `metadata.json` file would be something like

```
  "dependencies": [
    { "name":"puppetlabs/apt","version_requirement":"6.0.0" },
    { "name": "mycompany/moduleb", "version_requirement": "> 0.0.1" }
  ]
```

with the `moduleb` containing the importable functions. This probably means that you can't use the Puppet forge correctly, but if you are dealing with this problem you likely aren't losing much there.